# reftex-complete failed with (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)

Tags: org-mode, latex

In org-mode, in a file with a `\bibliography` line, <kbd>C-c [</kbd> failed. With [`(setq debug-on-error t)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5414033/1587329), the error message was

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  re-search-forward(nil 10001 t)
  tex-main-file()
  reftex-TeX-master-file()
  reftex-tie-multifile-symbols()
  reftex-access-scan-info(nil)
  reftex-citation()
  funcall-interactively(reftex-citation)
  call-interactively(reftex-citation nil nil)
  command-execute(reftex-citation)
```

It has worked intermittently before. How to get it working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system lacked the `auctex` package. `tex-main-file` referred to the non-existing file `tex-mode.el`.

Install `auctex` to fix this. F.ex. for Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install auctex
```

fixed the problem.